# ExtJS Grid - cellediting and key navigation

Tags: extjs, grid

Hello,

I am attempting to enable key navigation with cellediting plugin. For that I added specialkey listener on the editor then start edit on the cell surrounding the current one when the user press any navigation keys.

Here is the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1uss)

In order to find the next cell to edit I am using the selection model.

Unfortunately everything falls apart when the grid is locked since now we have 2 physical grid, and somehow the selection model is no longer a viable option to navigate to a particular cell.

Coming to my question, what is the proper way to navigate to/target a cell at a given index(row, col)?
The algorithm I have so far is as follow:

- calculate the newRowIdx, newColIdx values
- focus on the cell at newRowIdx, newColIdx
- start edit at that position

The first part is just math and checking the bound constraints. The second part can be achieved with grid.getView().focusCell(position). The third part can be called on the plugin directly. In the case of a locked grid, part 2 will behave erratically(not sure if it is because of part 1).